# Как выполнить перекодировку нескольких файлов на сервере

Tags: find

Выполняю команду `find . -type f -exec enca -L russian -x CP-1251 {} \;` чтобы перекодировать все файлы в кодировку `windows cp-1251`. Но команда find ищет все файлы, дальше enca ругается на бинарные файлы `enca: Cannot convert './images/blog-4.jpg' from unknown encoding`. Как найти только текстовые файлы исключив бинарные и к найденным файла применить `enca` командой в одну строку? Подскажите пожалуйста

upd1:
на сервере так же присутствую файлы уже в кодировке cp-1251, как можно их обойти и не трогать?

Comment: формат файлов известен? `txt`?

Comment: Форматы php, js

Answer (score 2):

Так как формат файлов известен, можно написать регулярное выражения для поиска

```
find . -type f \( -iname \*.php -o -iname \*.js \) -exec enca -L russian -x CP-1251 {} \;
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял более точно свою задачу, дополнил в шапке "upd1", можно  как то это условие учесть?